# How can I center columns in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Why are the columns not centering with equal spaces between them in Bootstrap 5? Below is the code and fiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/juantamad/1o59tsqw/3/

```
<section>
  <div class="row text-center mb-5">
    <div class="col">Letters</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3 text-center container">
  <div class="col">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <p>B</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <p>D</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>E</h2>
    <p>F</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>G</h2>
    <p>H</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not centering because `.text-center` does not impact a column in the same fashion that it does text. You would need to use `.justify-content-center`.  They lack any spacing between them because you are applying your own custom CSS to the `.col-*` attribute, adding a border and padding.

You're also applying `.container` to a `.row` which isn't valid in any version of Bootstrap.  By correcting your CSS declarations and wrapping the content of each column in an element to house the padding / background styling you want you can achieve your goal.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container">
  <div class="row text-center mb-5">
    <div class="col">
      Letters
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3 justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-light border p-3">
        <h2>A</h2>
        <p>B</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-light border p-3">
        <h2>C</h2>
        <p>D</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-light border p-3">
        <h2>E</h2>
        <p>F</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-light border p-3">
        <h2>G</h2>
        <p>H</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```